# Exception in export data from hcatalog to teradata

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hcatalog

I am trying to export table to Teradata, using Sqoop.
Table data was created in mapreduce job in parquet format, then I created external table pointing to this data using Impala.

Here is comand i am running:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:teradata://<ip>/DATABASE=TESTDB --username <username> --password <password> \
    --hcatalog-database parq_xml --hcatalog-table <table_name> --table <table_name>
```

But it fails with next exception (showing only tail):

```
16/03/17 23:45:21 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.0-1.cdh5.4.0.p0.27/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-standalone.jar
16/03/17 23:45:21 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.0-1.cdh5.4.0.p0.27/lib/hive/lib/zookeeper.jar
16/03/17 23:45:21 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.0-1.cdh5.4.0.p0.27/lib/hive/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
16/03/17 23:45:21 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.0-1.cdh5.4.0.p0.27/lib/hive/lib/logredactor-1.0.2.jar
16/03/17 23:45:21 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities: Adding jar files under /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.0-1.cdh5.4.0.p0.27/bin/../lib/sqoop/../hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/storage-handlers to distributed cache (recursively)
16/03/17 23:45:21 WARN hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities: No files under /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.0-1.cdh5.4.0.p0.27/bin/../lib/sqoop/../hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/storage-handlers to add to distributed cache for hcatalog job
16/03/17 23:45:21 INFO common.ConnectorPlugin: load plugins in file:/home/ovlasyuk/xml/teradata.connector.plugins.xml
16/03/17 23:45:21 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from a null string
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from a null string
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:135)
        at com.cloudera.connector.teradata.exports.ExportJob.configureOutputFormat(ExportJob.java:176)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:425)
        at com.cloudera.connector.teradata.TeradataManager.exportTable(TeradataManager.java:97)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:81)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is that Teradata connector doesn't support Hcatalog.